# Zorba (XQuery) - using print functions

Tags: xml, xquery, zorba

I'm using Eclipse's XQDT with Zorba 0.9.5. I'm trying to call the Zorba internal function `zorba:print(...)` from within a FLWOR expression, but it gets ignored.

Specifically, I'm doing something like the following

```
import module namespace zorba =
      "http://www.zorba-xquery.com/zorba/internal-functions";

for $l in list 
  let $bar := <hello />
  let $foo := zorba:print($bar)
  return (<nothing/>)
```

I can't put the print statement on its own because sequential statements aren't allowed in FLWOR exressions.

Any idea how I can get `print` calls to work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the following:

You use a flwor-expression to call zorba:print. In a flwor you have lazy evalution and since you don't use $foo, zorba:print gets not executed.

So in order to get zorba:print executed, you have to use $foo in your flwor.

In the next release of zorba will be much better support for the new [XQuery Scripting Extension](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-sx-10/) and then it will be easy to enforce the execution of side effect functions.